# For Loop Problem Iterate Once in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, for-loop, return, nested-loops, codeigniter-4

I am wondering how my code is iterate once. It should 5 iterations. But when I removed **return $result**, it was showing error in View ***Invalid argument supplied for foreach()***. I've been trying by adding output code in **Model** and removed all code in **View**. Finally it show 5 iterations as what I want. But, how can I show the result in View?

My Model

```
public function getAllItem()
    {
        for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
            for($j=$i+1; $j<=5; $j++){
                $builder = $this->db->table('rating')
                            ->select('user.idUser, user.nmUser, rating.idBengkel,
                                    MAX( if(rating.idBengkel = '.$i.' , rating.nilai, 0 )) itemX,
                                    MAX( if(rating.idBengkel = '.$j.' , rating.nilai, 0 )) itemY')
                            ->join('user','user.idUser = rating.idUser', 'left')
                            ->where('rating.idBengkel', $i)
                            ->orWhere('rating.idBengkel', $j)
                            ->groupBy('rating.idUser');
                //var_dump($builder);
                
                $query = $builder->get();
                $result = $query->getResult();

                return $result;
}
```

My Controller

```
public function pcc_method()
    { 
        $model = new Admin_model();
        $data['all'] = $model->getAllItem();

        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('pcc_method',$data);
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
```

My View

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">idUser</th>
            <th scope="col">nmUser</th>
            <th scope="col">itemX</th>
            <th scope="col">itemY</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Looping select db from Admin.php --> 

          <?php foreach($all as $row):?>
            <tr>
              <td><?= $row->idUser;?></td>
              <td><?= $row->nmUser;?></td>
              <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><?= $row->itemX;?></td>
              <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><?= $row->itemY;?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Please give me solution for this problem.
Regards!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am sorry to answer this because the problem is in `VIEW` and I've asked my friend who gave good solution. Like what `@Javier Larroulet` was said that the array has to be stored into new declared `Array`. In my code I am using `$all[]` that storing array `$result`.

**Model**

```
public function getAllItem()
    {
        for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
            for($j=$i+1; $j<=5; $j++){
                $builder = $this->db->table('rating')
                            ->select('user.idUser, user.nmUser, rating.idBengkel,
                                    MAX( if(rating.idBengkel = '.$i.' , rating.nilai, 0 )) itemX,
                                    MAX( if(rating.idBengkel = '.$j.' , rating.nilai, 0 )) itemY')
                            ->join('user','user.idUser = rating.idUser', 'left')
                            ->where('rating.idBengkel', $i)
                            ->orWhere('rating.idBengkel', $j)
                            ->groupBy('rating.idUser');
                //var_dump($builder);
                
                $query = $builder->get();
                $result = $query->getResult();
                $all[] = $result;
             }
         }
                return $all;
}
```

In View, I was checking with `<?php echo $all[0][0]->idUser;?>` to show the result and I got it. Then I use `nested loop` because that is corresponding.

**View**

```
<?php foreach($all as $row):?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">idUser</th>
                <th scope="col">nmUser</th>
                <th scope="col">itemX</th>
                <th scope="col">itemY</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($row as $key => $val):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $val->idUser;?></td>
                    <td><?= $val->nmUser;?></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><?= $val->itemX;?></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-sm-3"><?= $val->itemY;?></td>
                </tr>           
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to codeigniter. It has to do with native PHP.

`return` stops the execution of the whole method and returns whatever data it's instructed to do so to whatever function or method calls the method your method.

If you need the loop to run 5 times and return the output of the 5 iterations, you need to store data in an auxiliary variable and then return THAT variable after the for loop stops.

Many choices here. The easiest would be to create a new arrayObject before the first loop starts (`$temp = new ArrayObject();`) and then replace:

`return $result`

For:

`$temp->append($result);`

This will store the output of each iteration in the temp object.

Then, outside of both loops:

`return $temp;`

And the model will return the whole output to the controller

Comment: the other solution would be to write a better SQL query, but we don't know the database structure and the desired output

Comment: It give me error "Call to a member function append() on array"

Comment: Weird. `append` is a valid PHP method for `ArrayObject` objects. Check your syntax

Comment: It also give "Class 'App\Models\ArrayObject' not found"

Comment: @KhamadAli oops, my bad.. it's `$temp = new ArrayObject();` editing the answer now